# SQLite journal file behaviour after crash caused by uncaught exception

Tags: sql, sqlite, transactions, rollback, journal

I am working on a project involving SQLite, I have a single database file and now I am testing the behaviour of my application in case of power loss or application crash. 
I successfully tested the rollback of the journal file in case of power failure but I am struggling with the behaviour of SQLite when the application crashes, for example because of an uncaught exception.

Let's suppose this scenario (the operations on the real db are much more complex than a single insert, that's why I am using explicitly the transactions):

```
sqlite3_exec(db, "BEGIN;", nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
/* other code (may be select, delete, update on the db or something not related to the db) */
sqlite3_exec(db, "INSERT INTO mytable(myvalue) VALUES(10);", nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
throw "exception"; /* something throws an exception here */
sqlite3_exec(db, "COMMIT;", nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
```

The result of the code above is that I have a journal file left on the disk. My expectation is that as soon as I start a connection with the db after the crash, the journal file is read automatically and a rollback is performed.

What I actually noticed is that the journal file is not touched until I begin another transaction, then independently from the result of this new transaction (commit or rollback) the changes I performed before the throw in the code above are automatically rolled back. Is this an expected behavior? Maybe because the journal file is not a hot-journal file since the crash did not happen during a rollback or a commit?

EDIT: probably I found the reason of this behavior. The autocommit mode in SQLite is enabled by default and is disabled only when a transaction is started manually, then it is enabled again once the manual transaction is finished (commit or rollback). If the crash or power loss happens after the begin of the transaction but before the end of the transaction, the autocommit is disabled and when the database is opened again the autocommit will still be disabled, therefore the journal file won't be processed unless a new transaction is started and finished (with rollback or commit). This does not happen if the crash or power loss happens while doing commit or rollback because in that very moment the autocommit feature is enabled again so the new time SQLite will do the rollback automatically.

Comment: Have you read https://www.sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html#_rollback ?

Comment: The tricky bit is realizing that sqlite doesn't try to acquire a lock on the database file until it first tries to read from it, which doesn't happen on open.